# Excel variable in formula

Tags: excel-formula

Good morning,

I've got an excel formula that looks like this :

```
=IF([@Date]>currentPeriod,#N/A,
    IF(
          SUM(
                TProgress[@[D Earned]],
                TProgress[@[D Adj Earned]],
                TProgress[@[I Earned]],
                TProgress[@[I Adj Earned]]
          )
          /
          SUM(
                TCost[[#Totals],[D Budget Hours]],
                TCost[[#Totals],[I Budget Hours]]
          )
          *
          TInterface[[#Totals],[Current Budget]]
          >
          TInterface[[#Totals],[Current Budget]],
          TInterface[[#Totals],[Current Budget]],
          SUM(
                TProgress[@[D Earned]],
                TProgress[@[D Adj Earned]],
                TProgress[@[I Earned]],
                TProgress[@[I Adj Earned]]
          )
          /
          SUM(
                TCost[[#Totals],[D Budget Hours]],
                TCost[[#Totals],[I Budget Hours]]
          )
          *
          TInterface[[#Totals],[Current Budget]]
    )
)
```

Which is pretty ridiculous.  This is a project management sheet which calculates the earned cost.  Earned cost can never be above the current budget.  Is there a way to declare a variable for this calculation in the same cell instead of repeating it twice?  I don't want to have to hide formulas in other cells, it just makes it messy and hard to trace.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: If you do not want to put the main formula in another cell and then refer to it, then you are stuck with this long formula or vba.  Formulas do not have or allow declarations and use of variables.  As Excel assumes that if you want to do that you would use another cell as that variable.

Comment: I was hoping for a better option.  I'd rather have my calculation for earned cost be in one place, rather than hunting around to debug; or for others to understand the calculation.  To start using intermediary cells now would just be spaghetti.  Thanks for weighing in.

Comment: BTW you can shorten the logic in the second IF to `IF(SUM(
                TProgress[@[D Earned]],
                TProgress[@[D Adj Earned]],
                TProgress[@[I Earned]],
                TProgress[@[I Adj Earned]]
          )
          <
          SUM(
                TCost[[#Totals],[D Budget Hours]],
                TCost[[#Totals],[I Budget Hours]]
          ),...`

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks!  That saves 4 lines :)

Answer (score 0):

Some thing to the effect of

```
   IF([@Date]>currentPeriod,#N/A,
   MIN(TInterface[[#Totals],[Current Budget]],
          SUM(
            TProgress[@[D Earned]],
            TProgress[@[D Adj Earned]],
            TProgress[@[I Earned]],
            TProgress[@[I Adj Earned]]
             )
         /
          SUM(
            TCost[[#Totals],[D Budget Hours]],
            TCost[[#Totals],[I Budget Hours]]
             )
         *
            TInterface[[#Totals],[Current Budget]]
      )
```

would do the trick